# Api fetch - Cannot read property 'json' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

I'm working with this API for a map and I implemented some verification in case there is an error fetching the data. When implementing this solution, I get an error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'json' of undefined

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.citybik.es/v2/networks')
        .then(res => {                        // *** implemented this
            if (!res.ok) {                    // ***
                throw new Error(res.status);  // ***
            }                                 // ***
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
        .then(res => res.json()) // *** error in this line
        .then(response => {
            const networkData = response.networks;
            this.setState({
                bikeData: networkData
            });
        })
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: You don't return anything from the first then, it only handles error cases.

Comment: What do you suggest? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Either combine them, or return something for the second one to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to continue promise chaining, you should return a value for the next `.then` method. So, you are missing this return value in your first `.then` method. As @jonrsharpe explained in the comments you can combine those.

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("https://api.citybik.es/v2/networks")
    .then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(res.status);
      }
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(response => {
      const networkData = response.networks;
      this.setState({
        bikeData: networkData
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe and devserkan!